# Check if DataGridViewComboBoxColumn has empty value

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a datagridview with one `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` column and a button Submit outside datagridview which is updating all the data from datagridview in the database table. I would like to check if all the rows of combobox column is updated. In short I do not want an empty field in the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

In my submit button click event I am looping through all the rows of datagridview like the example shown below, and fetching value of each of the cell.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  rw.Cells["Label"].Value.ToString();
  ...
}
```

Before updating the data I would like to validate the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column to check it is not empty.

Comment: So what is the problem with your approach? I assume that you are actually trying to use: `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.Cells["Label"].Value.ToString())){}`

Comment: This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404353%28VS.80%29.aspx) may be useful for you

Comment: `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw.Cells["Label"].Value.ToString())){}` would check for a single value at a time. I want to check values of combobox column of entire datagrid.